# InfoSchema User Missing

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0

I have awoken this morning to an issue with my DB which shows the following error when running `show databases;` `show tables;`

`ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist`

I have not upgraded manually so not sure whats causing this, tried running mysql_upgrade but it appears to be deprecated.

I tried creating the user manually with these commands but encounter the following errors;

```
DROP USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';

mysql> DROP USER 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user]
mysql>
```

Also worth adding; I have tried restoring to 5 backups with my VPS provider over the last 5 days and the issue remains, so I can only presume that MySQL is auto upgrading itself?

Server Details: `Server version: 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)`

Any help would be greatly appreactied.

Answer (score 1):

Try to force upgrade. Add upgrade=FORCE to mysqld.cnf and restart Mysql server.